# No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.Predef.Map[java.lang.String, scala.Option[scala.Double]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

Trying to write a json format for an entity which contains a Map of Option. It throws following error

> Error:(8, 68) No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.Predef.Map[java.lang.String, scala.Option[scala.Double]] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)

Code snippet:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

val a: Map[String, Option[Double]] = Map("a" -> None)

case class Person(x: Map[String, Option[Double]])

object Person {
  implicit val personFormat: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person]
}

Json.toJson(Person(a))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define implicits:

```
  import scala.collection.Map

  object Person {
    implicit object MapReads extends Reads[Map[String, Option[Double]]] {
      def reads(jsValue: JsValue): JsResult[Map[String, Option[Double]]] = jsValue match {
        case JsObject(map) => JsSuccess(
          map.mapValues {
            case JsNumber(d) => Some(d.toDouble)
            case _ => None
          }
        )
        case _ => JsError()
      }
    }

    implicit object MapWrites extends Writes[Map[String, Option[Double]]] {
      def writes(map: Map[String, Option[Double]]): JsValue =
        JsObject(map.mapValues(optd => JsNumber(optd.getOrElse[Double](0.0))))
    }

    implicit val personFormat: OFormat[Person] = Json.format[Person]
  }

  println(Json.toJson(Person(a)))//{"x":{"a":0}}
```

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851919/5249621).

Comment: Mapping the None value to 0.0 may not be a good solution, as it's a valid value. None should be mapped to null.

Comment: Made following changes to implicit writes and now it returns null for None. `def writes(map: Map[String, Option[Double]]): JsValue =
      JsObject(map.mapValues {
        case None    => JsNull
        case Some(x) => JsNumber(x)
      })`

Comment: @SujitKamthe Yes, this was just an example how to define such implicits.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the inability of play-json macros to work with nested type variables:

`Map[String, Option[Double]]`

You could use an intermediate type wrapping Option

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class OptionDouble(value: Option[Double])
case class Person(x: Map[String, OptionDouble])

implicit val optionDoubleFormat = Json.format[OptionDouble]
implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]

val a: Map[String, OptionDouble] = Map("a" -> OptionDouble(None))
Json.toJson(Person(a))
```

Another option could be to write the formatter by hand.